# RxJS: show loading if request is slow

Tags: javascript, promise, spinner, rxjs

I thought of using RxJS to solve elegantly this problem, but after trying various approaches, I couldn't find out how to do it...

My need is quite common: I do a Rest call, ie. I have a Promise.
If the response comes quickly, I just want to use the result.
If it is slow to come, I want to display a spinner, until the request completes.
This is to avoid a flash of a the spinner, then the data.

Maybe it can be done by making two observables: one with the promise, the other with a timeout and showing the spinner as side effect.
I tried `switch()` without much success, perhaps because the other observable doesn't produce a value.

Has somebody implemented something like that?

Comment: Two promises should work, yes. Can you show us the code you tried?

Comment: Thanks for asking, @Bergi. I finally posted a solution, with a link to the Plunker I made for this experiment (previous tries were too messy...). Of course, other solutions are welcome

Comment: Most coders don't worry about spinner-flash. Delaying the spinner can never eliminate the possibility of a short flash, only shift it downstream in time. And the more it is delayed, the longer your users will be left without an indication of background activity, which is a spinner's purpose. Also, remember that the ultra-short latencies you experience in (local) development will typically increase in the live environment (busier server, internet delays ...)

Answer (score 5):

Based on @PhiLho's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35491598/3182091), I wrote a pipeable operator, which does exactly that:

```
export function executeDelayed<T>(
    fn : () => void,
    delay : number,
    thisArg? : any
) : OperatorFunction<T, T> {
    return function executeDelayedOperation(source : Observable<T>) : Observable<T> {
        let timerSub = timer(delay).subscribe(() => fn());
        return source.pipe(
            tap(
                () => {
                    timerSub.unsubscribe();
                    timerSub = timer(delay).subscribe(() => fn());
                },
                undefined,
                () => {
                    timerSub.unsubscribe();
                }
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Basically it returns a function, which gets the `Observable` `source`.
Then it starts a `timer`, using the given `delay`.
If this timer emits a `next`-event, the function is called.
However, if the source emits a `next`, the `timer` is cancelled and a new one is startet.
In the `complete` of the source, the `timer` is finally cancelled.
This operator can then be used like this:

```
this.loadResults().pipe(
    executeDelayed(
        () => this.startLoading(),
        500
    )
).subscribe(results => this.showResult())
```

I did not wirte many operators myself, so this operator-implementation might not be the best, but it works.
Any suggestions on how to optimize it are welcome :)

**EDIT:**
As @DauleDK mentioned, a error won't stop the timer in this case and the `fn` will be called after `delay`. If thats not what you want, you need to add an `onError`-callback in the `tap`, which calls `timerSub.unsubscribe()`:

```
export function executeDelayed<T>(
    fn : () => void,
    delay : number,
    thisArg? : any
) : OperatorFunction<T, T> {
    return function executeDelayedOperation(source : Observable<T>) : Observable<T> {
        let timerSub = timer(delay).subscribe(() => fn());
        return source.pipe(
            tap(
                () => {
                    timerSub.unsubscribe();
                    timerSub = timer(delay).subscribe(() => fn());
                },
                () => timerSub.unsubscribe(),   // unsubscribe on error
                () => timerSub.unsubscribe()
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it just me, or is the fn also called when an error is emitted?

Comment: @DauleDK The `fn` is called after `delay`, except, if `timerSub.unsubscribe()` is called. For errors, that is not the case, as the `onError` callback is set to `undefined`. So, if an error occures, the `fn` will still be called after the `delay`. If thats not what you want, you need to add `timerSub.unsubscribe()` in `onError`

Comment: You are a legend. Where did you learn/read about how to create custom pipeable-operators?

Comment: @DauleDK I actually just had a look at a few operators [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/tree/master/src/internal/operators). Then I stated with a simple operator, which executes a `flatMap` only if a given function returns true and returns a default value otherwise. This operator was pretty simple and I actually only had to copy + paste one of the existing operators and customize it a bit. So, there is nothing legendary about it :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example that I have used. We assume here that you get the data that you want to send to the server as an Observable as well, called `query$`. A query coming in will then trigger the `loadResults` function, which should return a promise and puts the result in the `results$` observable.

Now the trick is to use `observable$.map(() => new Date())` to get the timestamp of the last emitted value.

Then we can compare the timestamps of the last query and the last response that came in from the server.

Since you also wanted to not only show a loading animation, but wanted to wait for 750ms before showing the animation, we introduce the delayed timestamp. See the comments below for a bit more explanation.

At the end we have the `isLoading$` Observable that contains `true` or `false`. Subscribe to it, to get notified when to show/hide the loading animation.

```
const query$ = ... // From user input.

const WAIT_BEFORE_SHOW_LOADING = 750;

const results$ = query$.flatMapLatest(loadResults);

const queryTimestamp$ = query$.map(() => new Date());
const resultsTimestamp$ = results$.map(() => new Date());
const queryDelayTimestamp$ = (
    // For every query coming in, we wait 750ms, then create a timestamp.
    query$
    .delay(WAIT_BEFORE_SHOW_LOADING)
    .map(() => new Date())
);

const isLoading$ = (
    queryTimestamp$.combineLatest(
        resultsTimestamp$,
        queryDelayTimestamp$,
        (queryTimestamp, resultsTimestamp, delayTimestamp) => {
            return (
                // If the latest query is more recent than the latest
                // results we got we can assume that
                // it's still loading.
                queryTimestamp > resultsTimestamp &&
                // But only show the isLoading animation when delay has passed
                // as well.
                delayTimestamp > resultsTimestamp
            );
        }
    )
    .startWith(false)
    .distinctUntilChanged()
);
```

Comment: You don't really need to compare Dates. You can simply increment a counter for each query/delay/etc. In other words, replace `new Date()` with `++myCounter`.  You also need to add `delayTimestamp > queryTimestamp` to your `isLoading` calculation to prevent old queries from influencing the result.

Answer (score 1):

OK, thinking more about it in my commuting, I found a solution...

You can find my experiment ground at http://plnkr.co/edit/Z3nQ8q

In short, the solution is to actually subscribe to the observable handing the spinner (instead of trying to compose it in some way).
If the result of the Rest request comes before the observable fires, we just cancel the spinner's disposable (subscription), so it does nothing.
Otherwise, the observable fires and display its spinner. We can then just hide it after receiving the response.

Code:

```
function test(loadTime)
{
  var prom = promiseInTime(loadTime, { id: 'First'}); // Return data after a while
  var restO = Rx.Observable.fromPromise(prom);

  var load = Rx.Observable.timer(750);
  var loadD = load.subscribe(
    undefined,
    undefined,
    function onComplete() { show('Showing a loading spinner'); });

  restO.subscribe(
    function onNext(v) { show('Next - ' + JSON.stringify(v)); },
    function onError(e) { show('Error - ' + JSON.stringify(e)); loadD.dispose(); },
    function onComplete() { show('Done'); loadD.dispose(); }
  );
}

test(500);
test(1500);
```

Not sure if that's an idiomatic way of doing this with RxJS, but it seems to work...
Other solutions are welcome, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution :

```js
public static addDelayedFunction<T>(delayedFunction: Function, delay_ms: number): (mainObs: Observable<T>) => Observable<T> {
    const stopTimer$: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();
    const stopTimer = (): void => {
        stopTimer$.next();
        stopTimer$.complete();
    };
    const catchErrorAndStopTimer = (obs: Observable<T>): Observable<T> => {
        return obs.pipe(catchError(err => {
            stopTimer();
            throw err;
        }));
    };
    const timerObs: Observable<any> = of({})
        .pipe(delay(delay_ms))
        .pipe(takeUntil(stopTimer$))
        .pipe(tap(() => delayedFunction()));
    return (mainObs: Observable<T>) => catchErrorAndStopTimer(
        of({})
            .pipe(tap(() => timerObs.subscribe()))
            .pipe(mergeMap(() => catchErrorAndStopTimer(mainObs.pipe(tap(stopTimer)))))
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just before fetching the data, ie. creating the spinner, set timeout for a function, which creates the spinner. Lets say you are willing to wait half a second, until showing spinner... it would be something like:

```
spinnerTimeout = setTimeout(showSpinner, 500)
fetch(url).then(data => {
  if (spinner) {
    clearTimeout(spinnerTimeout) //this is critical
    removeSpinnerElement()
  }
  doSomethingWith(data)
});
```

EDIT: if it's not obvious, clearTimer stops the showSpinner from executing, if the data arrived sooner than 500ms(ish).

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I wanted a solution with RxJS. Well, maybe your answer, with clearTimeout, pushed me on the right direction... So thanks.