# Loading indication with a delay and anti-flickering in RxJS

Tags: angular, rxjs

I want to implement loading indication using RxJS (version 6). A loading indicator (a spinner) would be shown in a component before asynchronous data call finishes. I have some rules to implement (whether these rules are correct might be another question, maybe leave a comment):

- If the data arrives successfully earlier than in 1 second, no indicator should be shown (and data should be rendered normally)
- If the call fails earlier than in 1 second, no indicator should be shown (and error message should be rendered)
- If the data arrives later than in 1 second an indicator should be shown for at least 1 second (to prevent flashing spinner, the data should be rendered afterwards)
- If the call fails later than in 1 second an indicator should be shown for at least 1 second
- If the call takes more than 10 seconds the call should be canceled (and error message displayed)

I am implementing this in an Angular project, but I believe, that this is not Angular specific.

I have found some pieces of this puzzle, but I need help to assemble them together.

[In this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50352312) there is an implementation of an operator that delays the showing of a loading indicator.

A nice but incomplete implementation for Angular is described in [this article](https://nils-mehlhorn.de/posts/indicating-loading-the-right-way-in-angular/).

Showing loading indicator for a minimum amount of time is described in [this Medium article](https://codeburst.io/rxjs-show-spinner-for-a-minimum-amount-of-time-807ac6b23227).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

First of all, this is a nice question, Lukas!

*Foreword: while there are other ways to achieve what you ask, I just wanted to make my answer more like a detailed step-by-step tutorial. Do take a look at Brandon's amazing solution, right below this one.*

For convenience, let's imagine that we have a method that does the request and returns us an Observable of string messages:

```js
const makeARequest: () => Observable<{ msg: string }>;
```

Now we can declare our Observables that will hold the result:

```js
// Our result will be either a string message or an error
const result$: Observable<{ msg: string } | { error: string }>;
```

and a loading indication:

```js
// This stream will control a loading indicator visibility
// if we get a true on the stream -- we'll show a loading indicator
// on false -- we'll hide it
const loadingIndicator$: Observable<boolean>;
```

Now, to solve #1

> If the data arrives successfully earlier than in 1 second, no indicator should be shown (and data should be rendered normally)

We can set a [timer](https://thinkrx.io/rxjs/timer/) for 1 second and turn that timer event into a `true` value, meaning that loading indicator is shown. `takeUntil` will ensure that if a `result$` comes before 1 second — we wont show the loading indicator:

```js
const showLoadingIndicator$ = timer(1000).pipe(
  mapTo(true),       // turn the value into `true`, meaning loading is shown
  takeUntil(result$) // emit only if result$ wont emit before 1s
);
```

#2

> If the call fails earlier than in 1 second, no indicator should be shown (and error message should be rendered)

While the first part will be solved by #1, to show an error message we'll need to catch an error from the source stream and turn it into some sort of `{ error: 'Oops' }`. A [catchError](https://thinkrx.io/rxjs/catch/) operator will let us do that:

```js
result$ = makeARequest().pipe(
  catchError(() => {
    return of({ error: 'Oops' });
  })
)
```

You might've noticed that we're kind of using the `result$` in two places. This means that we'll have two subscriptions to the same request Observable, which will make two requests, which is not what we desire. To solve this, we can simply [share](https://thinkrx.io/rxjs/share/) this observable among subscribers:

```js
result$ = makeARequest().pipe(
  catchError(() => { // an error from the request will be handled here
    return of({ error: 'Oops' });
  }),
  share()
)
```

#3

> If the data arrives later than in 1 second an indicator should be shown for at least 1 second (to prevent flashing spinner, the data should be rendered afterwards)

First, we have a way to turn the loading indicator *on*, though we currently don't turn it *off*. Lets use an event on the `result$` stream as an notification that we can hide the loading indicator. Once we receive a result — we can hide the indicator:

```js
// this we'll use as an off switch:
result$.pipe( mapTo(false) )
```

So we can `merge` the on-off switching:

```js
const showLoadingIndicator$ = merge(
  // ON in 1second
  timer(1000).pipe( mapTo(true), takeUntil(result$) ),

  // OFF once we receive a result
  result$.pipe( mapTo(false) )
)
```

Now we have loading indicator switching *on* and *off*, though we need to get rid of loading indicator being flashy and show it at least for 1 second. I guess, the simplest way would be to [combineLatest](https://thinkrx.io/rxjs/combineLatest/) values of the *off* switch and a 2 seconds [timer](https://thinkrx.io/rxjs/timer/):

```js
const showLoadingIndicator$ = merge(
  // ON in 1second
  timer(1000).pipe( mapTo(true), takeUntil(result$) ),

  // OFF once we receive a result, yet at least in 2s
  combineLatest(result$, timer(2000)).pipe( mapTo(false) )
)
```

*NOTE:* this approach might give us a redundant *off* switch at 2s, if the result was received before 2nd second. We'll deal with that later.

#4

> If the call fails later than in 1 second an indicator should be shown for at least 1 second

Our solution to #3 already has an anti-flash code and in #2 we've handled the case when stream throws an error, so we're good here.

#5

> If the call takes more than 10 seconds the call should be canceled (and error message displayed)

To help us with cancelling long-running requests, we have a [timeout](https://thinkrx.io/rxjs/timeout/) operator: it will throw an error if the source observable wont emit a value within given time

```js
result$ = makeARequest().pipe(
  timeout(10000),     // 10 seconds timeout for the result to come
  catchError(() => {  // an error from the request or timeout will be handled here
    return of({ error: 'Oops' });
  }),
  share()
)
```

We're almost done, just a small improvement left. Lets start our `showLoadingIndicator$` stream with a `false` value, indicating that we're not showing loader at the start. And use a `distinctUntilChanged` to omit redundant *off* to *off* switches that we can get due to our approach in #3.

To sum up everything, heres what we've achieved:

```js
const { fromEvent, timer, combineLatest, merge, throwError, of } = rxjs;
const { timeout, share, catchError, mapTo, takeUntil, startWith, distinctUntilChanged, switchMap } = rxjs.operators;


function startLoading(delayTime, shouldError){
  console.log('====');
  const result$ = makeARequest(delayTime, shouldError).pipe(
    timeout(10000),     // 10 seconds timeout for the result to come
    catchError(() => {  // an error from the request or timeout will be handled here
      return of({ error: 'Oops' });
    }),
    share()
  );
  
  const showLoadingIndicator$ = merge(
    // ON in 1second
    timer(1000).pipe( mapTo(true), takeUntil(result$) ),
  
    // OFF once we receive a result, yet at least in 2s
    combineLatest(result$, timer(2000)).pipe( mapTo(false) )
  )
  .pipe(
    startWith(false),
    distinctUntilChanged()
  );
  
  result$.subscribe((result)=>{
    if (result.error) { console.log('Error: ', result.error); }
    if (result.msg) { console.log('Result: ', result.msg); }
  });

  showLoadingIndicator$.subscribe(isLoading =>{
    console.log(isLoading ? '⏳ loading' : ' free');
  });
}


function makeARequest(delayTime, shouldError){
  return timer(delayTime).pipe(switchMap(()=>{
    return shouldError
      ? throwError('X')
      : of({ msg: 'awesome' });
  }))
}
```

```html
<b>Fine requests</b>

<button
 onclick="startLoading(500)"
>500ms</button>

<button
 onclick="startLoading(1500)"
>1500ms</button>

<button
 onclick="startLoading(3000)"
>3000ms</button>

<button
 onclick="startLoading(11000)"
>11000ms</button>

<b>Error requests</b>

<button
 onclick="startLoading(500, true)"
>Err 500ms</button>

<button
 onclick="startLoading(1500, true)"
>Err 1500ms</button>

<button
 onclick="startLoading(3000, true)"
>Err 3000ms</button>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@6.5.2/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Great explanation! I end up using your solution. I have partitioned the `result$` stream into `data$` and `error$` using [partition](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/partition). Then I have subscribed to these and the `loading$` stream using 3 `async` pipes in Angular template. Unfortunately the timeout stopped working in that case. The `result$` emitted another value even after timeout. Any ideas why?

Comment: @LukasTrumm, first of all, I'm glad to help! Yet be sure to check Brandon's answer as well — I've learned a trick with throttleTime config from it. Regarding `timeout` and `partition` — it should still work with that setup. Heres an example of partition with our flow: https://thinkrx.io/gist/f5e88f52f588e6a3c8f604b9488f7da3 . You can play with timings and errors, though be sure to stay in 1s time (its that playground limit). If you'll still have issues — feel free to share your code so I could check it. GL

Comment: Great answer! I just don't get the part where "the data should be rendered afterwards". I see spinner is correctly loading for at least one second, but data is rendered immediately. You can see it with the 1500ms request: order is free -> loading -> Result: awesome -> free while I would expect free -> loading -> free -> Result: awesome. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Alessandro, hi! Good point! This is because of the line `combineLatest(result$, timer(2000))...` in the `showLoadingIndicator$` pipe. It waits for `result$` to emit **and only then emits itself**. So, as you said, the sequence would be: ... -> Result -> free. If you need to ensure the sequence, you can create another Observable that would `combineLatest` of `result$` and `showLoadingIndicator$.pipe(last())`. **OR** use another approach, like the one suggested by Brandon [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56366775/6921829) (I think it's cooler).

Comment: This is a really great solution. Thanks for the thorough explanation.

Comment: great explanation. But on every button click you create a whole set of new observables. Any idea how to reuse same observables (by having onclick stream)?

Comment: Check out Brandon's great answer just below: its much simpler and has a single stream, sourced from another stream — you'll easily adapt it to your needs! (e.g. if you derive `query$` from `clicks$`).

Comment: Awesome! Just one question, shouldn't `result$` be piped into `mapTo(false)` so `distinctUntilChanged` works as expected?

Comment: @The.Wolfgang.Grimmer , Please, note that `showLoadingIndicator$` merges two streams, both having a `mapTo`. Thus we have only `true` / `false` values on the stream.

Comment: @kos, oh i damn. Just misread it i thought the `mapTo` is piped into the `timer(2000)`.  It was confusion on my part.

Comment: @The.Wolfgang.Grimmer , no probs. The code is quite messed tbh :D Be sure to also check out Brandon's answer down below! It's more straightforward!

Comment: @kos I've created a custom rxjs operator named `showLoaderTime` that uses this approach. If you don't mind can you check the code if i'm doing this correctly.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/show-loader-time?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/app/shared/helpers/operators/show-loader-time.operator.ts

Comment: @The.Wolfgang.Grimmer , looks great! :)

Answer (score 4):

Here's yet another version.  This one uses `timeout` to end the query at 10s.  And uses `throttleTime` to prevent the loader flashing.  It also only subscribes to the query once.  It produces an observable that will emit the `showLoader` boolean and eventually the result of the query (or an error).

```js
// returns Observable<{showLoader: boolean, error: Error, result: T}>
function dataWithLoader(query$) {
   const timedQuery$ = query$.pipe(
       // give up on the query with an error after 10s
       timeout(10000),
       // convert results into a successful result
       map(result => ({result, showLoader: false})),
       // convert errors into an error result
       catchError(error => ({error, showLoader: false})
   );

   // return an observable that starts with {showLoader: false}
   // then emits {showLoader: true}
   // followed by {showLoader: false} when the query finishes
   // we use throttleTime() to ensure that is at least a 1s
   // gap between emissions.  So if the query finishes quickly
   // we never see the loader
   // and if the query finishes _right after_ the loader shows
   // we delay its result until the loader has been
   // up for 1 second
   return of({showLoader: false}, {showLoader: true}).pipe(
       // include the query result after the showLoader true line
       concat(timedQuery$),
       // throttle emissions so that we do not get loader appearing
       // if data arrives within 1 second
       throttleTime(1000, asyncScheduler, {leading:true, trailing: true}),
       // this hack keeps loader up at least 1 second if data arrives
       // right after loader goes up
       concatMap(x => x.showLoader ? EMPTY.pipe(delay(1000), startWith(x)) : of(x))
   );
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I can't get the idea behind `of({showLoader: false}, {showLoader: true})`, why do you need that? Also, wont [throttleTime](https://thinkrx.io/rxjs/debounceTime-vs-throttleTime-vs-auditTime-vs-sampleTime/) suppress the result if it comes within 1st second, thus leaving us with forever `{showLoader: true}`? I might be missing something obvious, a bit tired atm. Again, I'm sorry if so.

Comment: The first false value will come through immediately. The following true value will be delayed 1 second (throttled) (If the result arrives before the 1 second the true value will be thrown away). The final trick: when the observable stream _completes_, throttle immediately releases the final value. this stream completes as soon as the result value is sent, causing throttle to release it to your subscriber without delay

Comment: So basically I’ve constructed a stream that sends a starting false immediately followed by a true and some time later by the query result. Throttle kicks in after the starting false to implement pretty much all of your requirements except for the 10s timeout

Comment: Actually now that I think about it this version won’t wait at least 1s after the loader appears if the result comes in right after. I’ll need to adjust it when I’m back at my computer

Comment: Maybe its not a [throttleTime](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/throttleTime) operator you mean? I'm sure we have a misunderstanding here. `throttleTime` wont split the `of(..)` thing and wont release a value upon source completion as it only **passes the first value in the timespan**. Please, see [this marble diagram](https://thinkrx.io/rxjs/debounceTime-vs-throttleTime-vs-auditTime-vs-sampleTime/) for further details

Comment: Seems they changed the api of throttleTime again.  Now there's a config to control it.  Passing `{leading:true, trailing:true}` gets the behavior I describe.

Comment: Wow! I didn't know there was a config option. Sorry. Even when linking it in my comment above I totally missed that! So I was wrong and now I've learnt something. **Thank you, Brandon!**

Answer (score 0):

You can try to construct a steam in a following fashion.

(Assuming `data$` is your data observable that emits when data comes and errors, when it fails)

```
import { timer, merge, of } from 'rxjs';
import { mapTo, map, catchError, takeUntil, delay, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators'


const startTime = new Date();
merge(
  data$.pipe(
    takeUntil(timer(10000)),
    map((data) => ({ data, showSpinner: false, showError: false })),
    catchError(() => of({ data: null, showSpinner: false, showError: true })),
    switchMap((result) => {
      const timeSinceStart = (new Date).getTime() - startTime.getTime();
      return timeSinceStart > 1000 && timeSinceStart < 2000 ? of(result).pipe(delay(2000 - timeSinceStart)) : of(result)
    }),
  )
  timer(1000).pipe(
    mapTo({ data: null, showSpinner: true, showError: false }),
    takeUntil(data$)
  ),
  timer(10000).pipe(
    mapTo({ data: null, showSpinner: false, showError: true }),
    takeUntil(data$)
  )
).subscribe(({ data, showSpinner, showError }) => {
   // assign the values to relevant properties so the template can
   // show either data, spinner, or error

});
```

Comment: Thank you. It seems well-arranged however I am not able to make it work. It also do not implement the rule, that the spinner should be visible for at least 1 second when it is displayed.

Comment: Why wouldn't it work? It worked when I tested it.
But you are right - this doesn't show spinner for at least 1 second in case the data observable emits between 1st and 2nd second.. I'll update my answer, if a good answer comes to my mind.

Comment: @LukasTrumm I have updated code that should delay the data emission, if it emits between 1st and 2nd second.. and thus the spinner should show for at least 1 second.

Comment: Nice, it seems to work. There is only a missing parenthesis after the switchMap. However I am having hard time understand the flow. I feel like there must be a better way than introducing a separate time tracker (new Date()...).

Comment: Yea, the separate time tracker is not ideal. kos in the other answer tried a somewhat similar approach with more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** My old answer had bugs...

I now built a pipeable operator which works, but it's huge. Maybe someone can provide some improvements `:)`

`preDelay` is the amount of milliseconds until the loading indicator shows.
`postDelay` is the amount of milliseconds that the loading indicator will at least be visible.

```js
const prePostDelay = (preDelay: number, postDelay: number) => (source: Observable<boolean>) => {
  let isLoading = false; // is some loading in progress?
  let showingSince = 0; // when did the loading start?

  return source.pipe(
    flatMap(loading => {

      if (loading) { // if we receive loading = true
        if (!isLoading) { // and loading isn't already running
          isLoading = true; // then set isLoading = true

          return timer(preDelay).pipe( // and delay the response
            flatMap(_ => {
              if (isLoading) { // when delay is over, check if we're still loading
                if (showingSince === 0) { // and the loading indicator isn't visible yet
                  showingSince = Date.now(); // then set showingSince
                  return of(true); // and return true
                }
              }

              return EMPTY; // otherwise do nothing
            })
          );
        }
      } else { // if we receive loading = false
        if (isLoading) {
          isLoading = false;

          // calculate remaining time for postDelay
          const left = postDelay - Date.now() + showingSince;
          if (left > 0) { // if we need to run postDelay
            return timer(left).pipe( // then delay the repsonse
              flatMap(_ => {
                if (!isLoading) { // when delay is over, check if no other loading progress started in the meantime
                  showingSince = 0;
                  return of(false);
                }

                return EMPTY;
              })
            );
          } else { // if there's no postDelay needed
            showingSince = 0;
            return of(false);
          }
        }
      }

      return EMPTY; // else do nothing
    })
  );
}
```

Usage:

```js
loadingAction1 = timer(1000, 2000).pipe(
  take(2),
  map(val => val % 2 === 0)
);

loadingAction2 = timer(2000, 2000).pipe(
  take(2),
  map(val => val % 2 === 0)
);

loadingCount = merge([loadingAction1, loadingAction2]).pipe(
  scan((acc, curr) => acc + (curr ? 1 : -1), 0)
);

loading = loadingCount.pipe(
  map(val => val !== 0)
);

loading.pipe(
  prePostDelay(500, 1000)
).subscribe(val => console.log("show loading indicator", val));
```